# passing down boolean object to a child component in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I am trying to refactor some react-typescript code and I want to make one general component, and call it with different parameters several times, instead of having several components that work in the same way.

So I am using redux as well, and the way it works is that in each component I call the redux state, and now I want to do it differently.
I have made a component that is called `DrawerItems` and in there I have defined :

```
type DrawerItemProps = {
    open: boolean,
    tabs: boolean[],
  }

const DrawerItems = ({ open, tabs }: DrawerItemProps) => {
.
.
.
}
```

in my parent component I have

```
  const jaTabs = useSelector((state: TabState) => state.JA.tabs);
  const checkedOpen = useSelector((state: TabState) => state.JA.open);
```

and then I want to pass the to my child component like:

```
<DrawerItems open={checkedOpen } tabs={jaTabs } />
```

this generates the error:

```
Type '{ trunk: boolean; hip: boolean; knee: boolean; ankle: boolean; }' is missing the following properties from type 'boolean[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 29 more.
```

My state looks like this:

```
export interface TabState {
    ja: {
        open : boolean;
        tabs : {
            trunk: boolean;
            hip: boolean;
            knee: boolean;
            ankle: boolean;
        }
    }
    //=================
    fp: {
        open : boolean;
        tabs : {
            clearanceSwing: boolean;
            footOrientation: boolean;
        }
    }
    //=================
    gt: {
        open : boolean;
        tabs : {
            gaitWidth: boolean;
            centerOfMass: boolean;
            eCenterOfMass: boolean;
        }
    }
    //=================
    tm: {
        open : boolean;
        tabs : {
            gaitSpeed: boolean;
            stancePhaseDuration: boolean;
            swingPhaseDuration: boolean;
                }
    }
    //=================
    distance: {
        open : boolean;
        tabs : {
            stepLength: boolean;
            strideLength: boolean;
            distanceWalked: boolean;
        }
    }
}
```

how can I correctly pass the boolean array down to my child component?
I want to be able to pass the tabs everytime to my `DrawerItem` how can I do that?

Comment: you defined your `tabs` type as an array of booleans but in your TabState interface, you have an object that contains boolean values. I believe this mismatch is what's raising an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the error because you are giving to **tabs** a different type to what really is. Here,

```
tabs: boolean[]
```

You are saying that tabs is an array of boolean. However here:

```
tabs : {
 trunk: boolean;
 hip: boolean;
 knee: boolean;
 ankle: boolean;
}
```

You are saying that tabs is an object with those keys. So what you can do is creating an interface that you can import in your **DrawerItems** component:

```
export interface ITabs{
 trunk: boolean;
 hip: boolean;
 knee: boolean;
 ankle: boolean;
}
```

```
tabs: ITabs;
```

Answer (score 1):

In your type declaration you declare `tabs` as a boolean array

```
type DrawerItemProps = {
    open: boolean,
    tabs: boolean[],
  }
```

But in your interface you declare the tabs as an object

```
export interface TabState {
    ja: {
        open : boolean;
        /// Here v
        tabs : {
            trunk: boolean;
            hip: boolean;
            knee: boolean;
            ankle: boolean;
        }
    }
// ...
```

The type error basically tells you that you pass the the wrong prototype (object instead of array) that's why the error states properties are missing.

I don't know what your further implementation is, so depending on that you could choose to use either objects or arrays.

Answer (score 1):

I would do the refactor in this way. Also you try to assign type of object in array type

```
export interface Tabs {
   trunk: boolean;
   hip: boolean;
   knee: boolean;
   ankle: boolean;
 }
    

export interface TabState {
    ja: {
        open : boolean;
        tabs : Tabs
    }
    //=================
    fp: {
        open : boolean;
        tabs : {
            clearanceSwing: boolean;
            footOrientation: boolean;
        }
    }
    //=================
    gt: {
        open : boolean;
        tabs : {
            gaitWidth: boolean;
            centerOfMass: boolean;
            eCenterOfMass: boolean;
        }
    }
    //=================
    tm: {
        open : boolean;
        tabs : {
            gaitSpeed: boolean;
            stancePhaseDuration: boolean;
            swingPhaseDuration: boolean;
                }
    }
    //=================
    distance: {
        open : boolean;
        tabs : {
            stepLength: boolean;
            strideLength: boolean;
            distanceWalked: boolean;
        }
    }
}
```

And in react component pass type in this way

```
type DrawerItemProps = {
    open: boolean,
    tabs: Tabs,
  }

const DrawerItems = ({ open, tabs }: DrawerItemProps) => {
.
.
.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's happening because u are passing to `DrawerItems` tab param an object with the type of "TabState ja prop", but define type of tab as `boolean[]`.

You can solve this problem using [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html)

```
type DrawerItemProps<T> = {
    open: boolean,
    tabs: T,
}

function DrawerItems<T>({ open, tabs }: DrawerItemProp) {
.
.
.
}
```

Or using pipe with [Lookup Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html) to extract nested types in TabState, something like this:

```
type DrawerItemProps = {
    open: boolean,
    tabs: TabState['ja']['tabs'] |  TabState['fp']['tabs'] | TabState['gt']['tabs'] ...etc
}
```